# Create a module in magento

Tags: magento, module

I have followed the magento tutorials to create a module. In the 3rd part "Part 3 - Magento Controller Dispatch". I have no problem to create a module.But in the Part 4, i am confusing about the layout,

How to create a page template in magento is written there.But, When i followed the code "create a file at"

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml
```

I have already the local.xml file in my theme. So i confused where can i create the file and add the lines

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="magentotutorial/helloworld/simple_page.phtml" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

I have already the local.xml file where the following lines are written.

left.permanent.callout

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.permanent.callout</name></action>
    <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
</reference>

<reference name="root">
    <remove name="global_messages" />
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="alert_global_messages" template="core/messages.phtml" before="-" />
</reference>
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="core/template" name="jquery_noconflict" template="jquery/noconflict.phtml" before="-" />
</reference>
```

Now, how can i add the line

in my local.xml file.

Comment: change the layout file name into "<module_name>.xml"

Comment: why ? I cant understand why you think like that ?

Comment: this is the correct way. Refer this [link] (http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.magentocommerce.com%2Fwiki%2Fcustom_module_with_custom_database_table&ei=pObjUcWbM9CxrAfQlIGwDw&usg=AFQjCNG8OQl_lHmWmWVKnQDmYSdnwP3Scw&sig2=f-P00aNPHDTuIUPFg8OkKQ&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bmk)